# Differences in visNetwork graph appearance with more than 1000 nodes

Tags: r, graph, vis.js, visnetwork

I'm using the visNetwork package in R to create interactive network graphs. However, I've noticed that the appearance of my graph changes significantly as soon as I include more than 1000 nodes.

nice rendering with <= 1000 nodes:
[image: nice rendering with <= 1000 nodes]

nodes clustered together with >= 1001 nodes:
[image: nodes clustered together with >= 1001 nodes]

Here's the code I am using:

```
    visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "1250px", width = "100%") %>%
      visIgraphLayout %>%
      visOptions(
        highlightNearest = list(
          enabled = T,
          degree = 1,
          hover = F
        ),
        nodesIdSelection = TRUE
      ) %>%
      visEdges(
        scaling = list(max = 5),
        color = list(opacity = 0.6),
        smooth = TRUE
      ) %>%
      visPhysics(
        solver = "forceAtlas2Based",
        forceAtlas2Based = list(springConstant = 0.785),
        stabilization = F
      ) %>%
      visNodes(font = list(size = 14, strokeWidth = 4),
               size = 11) %>%
      visConfigure(enabled = T) %>%
      visInteraction(navigationButtons = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE) %>%
      visLayout(randomSeed = 1) %>%  
      visSave("/some/path.html")
```

And here some example nodes and edges:

```
| id | label | title | centrality | shape | group |
| ---:|:--- |:--- | ---:|:--- | ---:|
| 1 | a | \<chr \[1\]\> | 31748 | dot | 1 |
| 2 | b | \<chr \[1\]\> | 18587 | dot | 5 |
| 3 | c | \<chr \[1\]\> | 11693 | dot | 3 |
| 4 | d | \<chr \[1\]\> | 12504 | dot | 5 |
| 5 | e | \<chr \[1\]\> | 18515 | dot | 2 |
| 6 | f | \<chr \[1\]\> | 16438 | dot | 3 |
| 7 | g | \<chr \[1\]\> | 3903 | dot | 5 |
| 8 | h | \<chr \[1\]\> | 11741 | dot | 5 |
| 9 | i | \<chr \[1\]\> | 10497 | dot | 4 |
| 10 | j | \<chr \[1\]\> | 10254 | dot | 1 |
```

```
| from | to | value |
| ---:| ---:| ---:|
| 1 | 1 | 12110. |
| 1 | 199 | 9165. |
| 1 | 322 | 9029. |
| 1 | 480 | 5059. |
| 1 | 150 | 3841. |
| 1 | 92 | 2598. |
| 1 | 468 | 2256. |
| 1 | 696 | 2086. |
| 1 | 897 | 2072. |
| 1 | 137 | 1640. |
```

By gradually adding more nodes, I have seen that it does not depend on the concrete node I add: as soon as it is > 1000 nodes, this problem occurs. I have also tried all the algorithms available in visNetwork (under physics -> solver), they all result in the same problem. I encounter the problem on different, not overlapping data sets (although the kind of data is similar)

Comment: I tried to reproduce with random graphs of differing sizes (999, 1000, 1001, 2000). All plot as a sphere for me. Are your packages up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the solution. It is the [default layout algorithm](https://igraph.org/r/html/1.2.3/layout_nicely.html) of the visIgraphLayout function. If I change it to layout_with_fr, it works!

> layout_nicely tries to choose an appropriate layout function for the supplied graph, and uses that to generate the layout. The current implementation works like this:
> If the graph has a graph attribute called ‘layout’, then this is used. If this attribute is an R function, then it is called, with the graph and any other extra arguments.
> Otherwise, if the graph has vertex attributes called ‘x’ and ‘y’, then these are used as coordinates. If the graph has an additional ‘z’ vertex attribute, that is also used.
> Otherwise, if the graph is connected and has less than 1000 vertices, the Fruchterman-Reingold layout is used, by calling layout_with_fr.